# JMeter:How to post cookie data in Request Header

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, blazemeter

I can able to get the "set-cookie" data by regular expression extractor/ by setting it in the JMeter user properties file but I can't get the following cookie data to use it in the "Request Header" as like defining user-agent.

**Cookie info displayed in the browser as follows:**

```
connection keep-alive  
User-Agent xxxxxx   
Cookie _ga=GA1.2.1710658689.1468689932
```

1. Where do I find the "`_ga`" Value such that I will use it.
2. What is the regular expression for it.

Kindly help me it is blocking.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way of automatically handling cookies is using [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar). If for some reason you need to use cookie value somewhere else - you can extract it as follows:

1. Add the next line to *user.properties* file  (lives in JMeter's "bin" folder)

   ```
   CookieManager.save.cookies=true
   ```
2. Restart JMeter to pick the property change up
3. Add HTTP Cookie Manager to your Test Plan
4. Refer extracted cookies as `${COOKIE_YOUR_COOKIE_NAME_HERE}` where required i.e. `${Cookie__ga}` in your case

User-Agent and any other headers can be specified via [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager).

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario it got worked without posting the above mentioned cookie. It worked by posting the set-cookie info and Location value in the header manager. Thanks!